# Updates Values on Excel and PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I wanted to create an excel file that calculates the days diference between a fixed date and today's date and display that value in a PPT.

1st Problem: If I change my date on the computer, the Today Cell does not change by itself; I tried to make a Vba code for Update but it didn't work

2nd Problem: the PPt value change automatically  But If I put the PPt in Presentation Mode I lose the connection, and I have to update the connection again.

Note: If there is a way to do all the calculation in the PPt it will be Correct

Thank you

Comment: There is as `DateDiff` function in VBA: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function. You don't need to go to Excel. `Date` returns the date of today.

Comment: For the first problem: Check Menu FORMULA->Calculation Options (far right in the menu)->AUTOMATIC. 
Maybe it is set to manual in your excel.

Comment: @Ike, I use excel because i wanna make a button For Reset ( Date x = Today )

Comment: @Chris , I make it on Automatique , I have changed the Windows Date but Nothing was haping

Comment: I don't think that an event will fire when you reset the Windows date that leads to a recalculate on the worksheet. You can create a reset-button within powerpoint as well ... as long as we don't see your code it is hard to give advice

Comment: @Ike , Thank you So much for give me time to Answer, I understand is there a way to update the value every hour for example?

Comment: To me it seems very, very strange to change the Windows date - why are you doing that?

Comment: this Presentation i will make it on TV all time , And every day i wanna have the difference between the 2 days with touching anything, So i guess for test i changed my Windows Date , I sorry im not an expert

Comment: Between which 2 days/dates? Did you read the link about `DateDiff`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function (this is the english version)

Comment: yes i tested , it's Work but the problem is still the update every day

Comment: is it ppt or pptx?